# How to solve CSS background transparency?

Tags: html, css

all
[image]

As you can see in images i have gradient background (this is responsive layout) and i want to display testimonials on that.
the problem is, i want the transparent bg.

i have tried to use this

```
.transparent {
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
```

}

but its shows something like this is not my solution
[image]

How can i set testimonials bg same as in my web site bg.
Can semi transparent png can sole this or any other way to solve it ?

thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you set `background: transparent` on that element?

Comment: @Ajay: I'm not sure about the problem... You want the background of the testimonials transparent, but not the text right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `rgba` as a background. This gives you the option of background opacity. Here's a little calculator I use all the time to get hex to rgba http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/.

I'm not quite sure if I understand the question, but that's what you can use if you want semi-transparency. For full transparency, just use `background: transparent`. And it should work.

EDIT: I believe I understand the question more now. The reason that you were getting the result, is because you were setting the entire element to be at opacity 0.5, not just the background. If you use `rgba` like i suggested, you can set the background to be semi-transparent like this

```
background: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.5);
```

Comment: but, the `background` property is `transparent` by default

Comment: i'm imagine that your main problem was trying to set opacity to 0 ;)

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
.transparent {
        /* Required for IE 5, 6, 7 */
        /* ...or something to trigger hasLayout, like zoom: 1; */
        width: 100%; 

        /* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */
        /* ...but not required as filter works too */
        /* should come BEFORE filter */
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

        /* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
        /* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);

        /* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
        -moz-opacity:0.5;

        /* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
        -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

        /* Modern!
        /* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
        /* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
        opacity: 0.5;
}
```

or something like this

```
.transeffect {
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity:0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: i think in my question you can see i have mentioned this css, from css-tricks and its not working for me